# Speak the Name of the Father! - Name the lord of the gods so that he may yet survive the theomachy

Tags: riddle

> *Our father was the first of our kind, though his many children and grandchildren rule over billions, caging them.*
>
> *I am a liberator, and my father shelters those who travel through water.*
>
> *Father once bled silver till there was none left to bleed, and my closest brother could no longer move; he was dead.*
>
> *Sister wisdom remains partially with us, though she will not come to our aid.*
>
> *Some of my siblings have revolted and hurry toward our doom. One of my brothers is the very hole of a noose. Another crafted weapons for the thrice born empire before coming after me.*
>
> *The Eight come, seven shadow siblings with curved blades, across the sea to feast upon iron and my father's heart. I alone remain faithful. And all along... the rumble... the smoke... the lightning flash... Speak my father's name and he may yet live.*

Comment: Wow, fantastically written riddle. Sounds like it's straight out of a fantasy novel!

Comment: Sounds like the Greek gods...

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 That was my first idea, maybe one of Poseidon's children, but there's no way to connect all of the clues.

Comment: _Father once bled [...] and my closest brother could no longer move; he was dead_ Who's dead? The father from bleeding or the brother for not moving?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe

> Ford? The car company?

**Reasoning:**

*The first of our kind*

> Not quite right, but a first with respect to mass production

*his many children and grandchildren rule over billions, caging them*

> Lots of other cars

*I am a liberator*

> Lincoln Motors/Abraham Lincoln

*my father shelters those who travel through water*

> Referring to fording a river

*Father once bled silver till there was none left to bleed, and my closest brother could no longer move; he was dead.*

> Mercury, a now-defunct sub-brand of Ford

*Sister Wisdom*

> Mazda, named after [Ahura Mazda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahura_Mazda) - "The literal meaning of the word Ahura is light and Mazda is wisdom." and Mazda used to have a partnership with Ford.

*The very hole of a noose*

> [Honda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_knot)

*Weapons for the thrice-born empire*

> Mitsubishi manufactured war planes during WW2 (Third Reich)

*The Eight*

> Perhaps Toyota? Wikipedia says the name's "eight-stroke count in the Japanese language was associated with wealth and good fortune", but I'm pretty much lost here.

*And all along... the rumble... the smoke... the lightning flash...*

> The internal combustion engine

Not sure about the revolting siblings and a few other bits, but I'll sleep on that.

Comment: Nice idea! +1 Could well be it.

Comment: Well done! Yes, your answer was entirely correct.

Comment: Whew, thanks! Nice puzzle - I learned a lot while looking that stuff up. So the part about the Eight was also correct? And does "revolting siblings" have a specific answer?

Comment: Thank you. It was. The theme of conflict and the revolting siblings was meant to represent their conflict with each other in the marketplace. Eight, being the meaning of Toyota's original spelling, is represented by Toyota's seven companies. I was using the shadow and curved blades to refer to the two most recognizable warrior types of the nation, ninja and samurai. Somewhat obvious, yes, but worried it would be needed. How did you first figure it out?

Comment: The hole of a noose was the most specific definition, so finding that tipped me off (though I kept looking for other terms for a few minutes after coming across the right one). Combined with caging billions + vaguely remembering the wisdom answer, it seemed like a solid link. Probably took a good hour or so to decode the rest.

Comment: Very nice. I was actually amazed that it took you so little time. I did notice that you got one unintended answer: Mitsubishi. While correct, I was trying to point to BMW, another Nazi producer of arms.

Comment: `seven shadow siblings with curved blades, across the sea to feast upon iron and my father's heart.` The Seven Samurai, refers to competition from Japanese cars. 8 is a lucky number in East Asia in general, not just in character stroke counts. (BTW That's why international dialling codes for the region were chosen to start with 8. )

Answer (score 3):

Your Father is

> The **Stomach** or The **Digestive System**

and you are

> the mouth (the only one faithful to your father)

though his many children and grandchildren rule over billions, caging them refers to

> the brain, muscles and bones

I am a liberator and my father shelters those who travel through water is about

> the food particles mixed with saliva and other stomach fluids and I am a liberator refers to the mouth

Father once bled silver till there was none left to bleed refers to

> excrement of metabolic waste

my closest brother could no longer move refers to

> any skull bone other than jaw bone

Sister wisdom remains partially with us, though she will not come to our aid refers to

> the brain and the brain can't control the hunger

Some of my siblings have revolted and hurry toward our doom refers to

> hunger

One of my brothers is the very hole of a noose refers to

> the anus

The Eight come, seven shadow siblings with curved blades, across the sea to feast upon iron and my father's heart refers to

> the rib cage

I alone remain faithful. And all along... the rumble... the smoke... the lightning flash... refers to

> the mouth receives/gets food for the digestive system or stomach (the father) and so mouth is the one faithful to his father.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a riddle for christian teaching to me.

> The father - God.

---

> One of my brothers is the very hole of a noose - Satan/The devil.

---

> Thrice born empire - Jesus dies twice, and is "born" three times.  (not perfectly accurate)

---

> Father once bled silver till there was none left to bleed - death on a cross.

---

> My closest brother could no longer move; he was dead - Satan/Death?

---

> I alone remain faithful - Jesus, the only human to never sin.

---

> The Eight come, seven shadow siblings with curved blades, across the sea to feast upon iron and my father's heart. - It's been a long time since I read Revelations (the last book in the bible), but I remember something about seven "beings of destruction".

Comment: Not sure if all these are correct, but your answer is wrong.